# Any hope to debug my Python3.1 process?

Tags: linux, debugging, python-3.x

there.
I have some code written for Python 3.1 that is misbehaving. If it was some C code, I'd just use `gdbserver`first, attach to the process (it's involved in a fairly sophisticated command line, where the python process receives its input on stdin), fire my favourite GDB front-end and I'll be ready to figure out why it's going wrong.

But it's python. I just tried the `pdb` module, but I can't interrupt the process when it goes off: I get a "KeyboardInterrupt" instead (and I need to change the rest of the command chain so that they give `set_ptrace` a go)

I tried winpdb, which produced curious error message

```
   Unhandled Exception (in pyshared/rpdb2.py)
```

and asked for a "password" before I could attach to the process. It gives me the overall feeling that winpdb is for python2 only.

I just tried `gdb __main__.py` in order to attach to the running process, but that says "format not recognized", as one could imagine.

Where is the manpage I've missed ?

PS: oh, it's a multi-threaded process, if that matters.

A minimal example:

```
import pdb

pdb.set_trace()  # press 'c' here to continue
while(True):
    print("hi")  # hit CTRL+C here ... will just kill the program with python 3.1

print("ooh")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way of using pdb is to put a line with:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

Where you want the break. If you want the break to be conditional, then you just add the condition, like:

```
if x > 1000:
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

No CTRL-C is involved.

However, a CTRL-C hook will be installed if you let the pdb module run the script:

```
python3 /path/to/stdlib/pdb.py myscript.py
```

A shorter and simpler way to write that is:

```
python3 -m pdb myscript.py
```

Some linux distributions will also make a link to pdb.py in /usr/bin, meaning you get it as a command:

```
pdb3 myscript.py
```

All these three commands above do the same thing. That thing is however different from the `pdb.set_trace()`, as pressing CTRL-C will then enter **post-mortem** debugging. That means you can't step through the code as the next step would be exiting the program. It is therefore much less useful than the above technique. It can however be a quick way to figure out what in your code is taking a lot of time, when it is running slow, and it will then allow you to put in a set_trace() in the correct place to figure out *why* it is slow.

It does also indeed as you indicate above, seem to be broken in Python 3.1. It does however work in Python 3.2.

It will only work in simple cases, though, in more complex cases you need to use profiling to find the culprit.

Comment: aha ? so you can move the symbol import out of the "module header section" and avoid leaving trails of your debugging activity ?

Comment: @sylvainulg: Well "trails" I don't know, but yes, pdb.set_trace() should go where you want the break, not at the beginning of the file (unless that's where you want it, which is useful when you have import problems, for example).

Comment: I was rather referring to `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` rather than import sys;import io;import pdb; ... lots of classes and stuff ... def buggy(self): ... pdb.set_trace() ...

Comment: @sylvainulg: Yes. I'm not what in my answer is confusing. Once again: Wherever you want to have a break, you put "import pdb;pdb.set_trace()". That's it. That's all you do. It's that simple. Now go do it. And upvote and select this answer. ;-)

Comment: sure. upvoting. I'm not sure about selecting as the answer, although noone else provided something better here: I still haven't the ability to interrupt the process on-demand wherever it is spending its effort, as I wished to do.

Comment: @sylvainulg: OK, I expanded the answer with a more in-depth version of Svens answer.

Comment: thanks for de-mystifying post-mortem vs. normal debugging to me :) That sounds a lot like a core dump, actually ...

Comment: @sylvainulg: It's similar in that you get the state when the Exception /crash happened, and you can't step forward, because there is no forward, true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `pdb` for this, which works fine for me.  After hitting Ctrl-C, you can post-mortem debug the state of your program, and you will have access to all stack frames in the traceback.  If you want to do live debugging, set a breakpoint where the Ctrl-C occurred and start again.

Comment: well, I guess I'm gonna try that on a "simplified" command chain, then.

Comment: looks like some signal-catching behaviour of pdb is different in 3.1 and don't install its own handler when the "continue" command is issued >_<

Comment: @sylvainulg: I installed Python 3.1.5 and tried it, and it works in 3.1.5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

My best take so far is thus to use pdb (indeed), but to call `set_trace()` only when a KeyboardInterrupt occurs. That appears to be the only working way in python 3.1

Answer (score 0):

A way to combine on-demand interruption and python-interpreter debugging could be to use *another signal*, such as SIGUSR1, let it alter a global "debugging" flag, and conditionally invoke `set_trace()` when debugging==True.